# class field theory via schemes?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

I know there is a close relationship between algebraic number theory and algebraic geometry. And in particular the theory of schemes is of many uses in algebraic number theory. Since I think the peak of the algebraic number theory is class field theory, I think there ought to be some applications of the schemes to CFT. But I have no relevant knowledge in this diretion, so any reference is welcomed. It would be the best if there is a book that developpes the class field theory out of schemes. :)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/73054/a-reference-for-geometric-class-field-theory

Comment: Thanks. I will have a look.

Comment: Sanchez's link pertains to class field theory for function fields. I've always been curious as to whether there is a way to geometrically discuss CFT for number fields.

Comment: @AlexYoucis: There is a series of blog-posts [here](https://justinsmath.wordpress.com/2013/02/15/geometric-class-field-theory-3/), which seems to do what I expected. (Still reading...)

Comment: Thanks for the blog post. :) If I'm not mistaken that is *geometric* class field theory. Not class field theory for number fields, no? Of course one would expect a geometric way of discussing geometric class field theory!

Comment: @AlexYoucis Then this might serve as a starting point for further works. :)